# Sales prediction for the next year

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, python, econometrics, prediction

I Have a homework problem. I need to predict sales for the next year and I have a condition that TRP for the next year = 4000. I don't know what I should begin with first.

[image]

```
TRP = Target rating point

TV spends = money spent on tv advertising
```

I tried to find all correletions between columns 
some column correlates quite good

```
corr(sales,TRP) = 0,767339893
corr(sales,tv_spends) = 0,655813295
corr(sales,TRP_Competitor) = 0,535788064
corr(TRP,tv_spends) = 0,849711793
corr(TRP,TRP_Competitor) = 0,39609449
corr(tv_spends,TRP_Competitor) = 0,178205839
```

And also found out that the sales depend on seasonality.(more sales in spring-summer)

If I had to predict only the one column and I knew others it would be easy, but I don't know other columns for 2019-2020 either.
It would be great if somebody could help me with what I need to begin with or send a link with a same problem.
P.S. I could do this not only in excel, python and R are also welcome)

Comment: What have you tried? You should post a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Try multiple linear regression (rather than correlation) keeping sales as outcome variable.

Comment: As a simpler version, since Sales and TRP are showing good correlation, you can use regression between these 2 variables and then find Sales for TRP=4000. You should post how you proceeded here once you post a question.